# ChartJS ignoring TailwindCSS styling

Tags: javascript, chart.js, tailwind-css

I implemented a simple Chart for visualisation und wanted to styling it's height und width using TailwindCSS like this:

```
  <div class="w-1/2 md:w-full h-full bg-gray-900">
    <canvas class="w-full h-full" id="myChart" />
  </div>
```

Chart Options:

```
options: {
          responsive: true,
          aspectRatio: 1
        }
```

While most of the time the outcome looks good, on some aspect ratios I get weird scalings:
[image]

Here the graph should be much smaller, since the Div is getting scaled down.:

[image]

---

However, when I add
height="100%" to the canvas HTML tag, the scaling works just fine:

```
  <div class="w-1/2 md:w-full h-full bg-gray-900">
    <canvas height="100%" class="w-full h-full" id="myChart" />
  </div>
```

[image]

Did I misuse the TailwindCSS operators (h-full), which has the same height=100% value, or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I tried these auto values but still couldn't get a good result

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution in my object options, where i had to add

> maintainAspectratio: false

to get the result i wanted:

```
options: {
          responsive: true,
          aspectRatio: 1,
          maintainAspectRatio: false
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Detecting when the canvas size changes can not be done directly from the canvas element. Chart.js uses its parent container to update the canvas render and display sizes. Check this [Doc](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/responsive.html#configuration-options)

```
<div class="relative m-auto w-1/2 h-auto" style="position: relative; height:40vh; width:80vw">
   <canvas class="w-full h-full" id="myChart" /> //give your target width & height
</div>
```